# How to test binomial result with repeated-measure and dependent sample

Tags: repeated-measures, binomial-distribution

Here is my design:

Participant must judge their ability to perform an action at several distances (condition). The result is binary (yes/no).

The participants perform this test on 3 different blocks in a row. That is, the participants performs the tests in an environment, then in a different environment and finally a final one.Therefore the samples are dependent.

I try to see if there is a significant difference between the blocks (effect of the environment), the conditions (effect of distances) and if there is an interaction.

Comment: What means "go through blocks"? What are "blocks"? What means "pass several times on several conditions (randomly)"? What are the "results"? Please be more clear with your description so we have a chance to help you.

Comment: @frank I have clarified the explanations, I hope it is more informative. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a dependent variable which is binomial (YES/NO) and 2 categorical variables: distance and environment.

Your data are dependent because participants judge their ability to perform an action at several distances in different environments.

In this case, I would approach it with a GLMM, with binomial error distribution. Where the ID is the participant's ID, the random effect.

```
library(lme4)
model<-glmer(dependent variable~distance*environment+(1|ID), family=binomial)
summary(model)
```

I hope I have helped you, best regards